# error 1084 as3: expecting > rightparen before colon

Tags: actionscript-3, inheritance, constructor

I have a subclass extended for a super Class

The constructor method in subclass is

```
public function Level1() {

            super(Level(_main:Main,_stage:Stage));

        }
```

since it takes two arguments so I am assuming have to be declared explicitly
,but I get the following error when I try to compile it

> "/Levels/Level1.as, Line 22, Column 21    1084: Syntax error: expecting
>   rightparen before colon."

not sure why?

Comment: Maybe this error can serve as a reason to think about whether these parameters make sense in the first place...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`super()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/statements.html#super)

> Invokes the superclass or parent version of a method or constructor. When used within the body of a class constructor, the super() statement invokes the superclass version of the constructor. The call to the superclass constructor must have the correct number of arguments ...

So when using `super()`, you are simply calling the constructor of your superclass, which give in your case :

```
super(_main, _stage);    // equivalent to : Level(_main, _stage);
```

You have just to pass the arguments you are not defining a new constructor.

Hope that can help.

Comment: Dear @akmozo.you should post an answer when the other answers are not enough or they are wrong.but your answer is the expanded version of mine but nothing new ! and are you still want to make an arrangement with me? you remember?

Comment: @HITMAN In my answer, I tried to explain things, and really I don't care if the OP select my answer or yours, the most important for me is that OP get an answer to his question. About the arrangement, I was talking about the OP not me !

Answer (score 0):

You should write:

```
super(arg1,arg2);
```

not:

```
super(Level(arg1,arg2));
```

If that is in line 22 so that's the problem.

I H☻ P E this helps

Comment: I changed it to super(_main:Main,_stage:Stage); still am getting the same error :(

Comment: I don't know about that problem.but there is another problem too.when you want to call a function, you should pass a value as arguments.not a value input ! I mean use:`super(myMain,myStage)` not `super(_main:Main,_stage:Stage)`. I think you need more basic trainings about AS3 if you don't mind ;)

Answer (score 0):

The thing is when you are calling a function you should never use the datatypes

```
 super(Level(_main,_stage));
```